# Application Server for non-Web Spring/Hibernate Application

Tags: spring, hibernate, algorithmic-trading, non-web

We are developing a open source trading platform based on Springframework and Hibernate http://code.google.com/p/algo-trader/ and http://www.algotrader.ch. The application consists of a trading framework and several strategies that can be started independently. So far, these different parts have been running in separate JVM's communicating through RMI and JMS.

To avoid unnecessary serialization and network overhead we would like to run the entire application within some sort of container (potentially an application server). We do however have the requirement, that the individual parts of the application can be deployed, started and stopped independently.

We have looked into OSGi, but a lot of the libraries that we use are not OSGi ready yet, so this is not currently an option. Also please note, there is no web-GUI in our application.

Any suggestions on this?
Thanks
Andy

Answer (score 0):

If OSGI is not an option then functionality can be broken into smaller units and then deploy them as utility jar, if deployed as utility jar they can be managed independently.

For application server I feel either glassfish or Jboss will be a good option considering they are open source and free.

Though at a later point in time you can check with Weblogic (Dev free).

So in your case you would like to break the static data configuration(Counterparty, Currencies), Dealing(Pricing, Quoting, Booking) as two separate feature.

Comment: thanks! it seams, that there is a lot of overhead with any of these application servers. In our case, we do not need any Web, EJB, Transaction Management, Clustering, Web Service features. Can glassfish / JBoss be run without all of these features?

Answer (score 0):

For your choose of an application server i advise you Jboss and specially in his version 7.1 which is faster and more stable!